# VBA Mismatch Error for outputting textbox entry with calculation to Excel sheet?

Tags: vba, mismatch

quite new to VBA and have what must be a rather simple question, but data types keep on giving me problems. I'm developing a MultiPage UserForm in VBA, and would like to output user input to Excel, to run calcs in the sheet and then provide an answer on a subsequent page in the UserForm. I've tried looking online for solutions, but nothing is clicking. Basically trying this:

```
Sheets("Calcs").Range("DataStart").Offset(0, 11).Value = CRBinQnt / 100 * Sheets("Calcs").Range("DataStart").Offset(0, 6).Value
```

So a user would input a number into a text box `CRBinQnt`, and I want to assign that number to `Sheets("Calcs").Range("DataStart").Offset(0, 11).Value` in Excel Worksheet. Before inputting that value, I would like it to be divided 100 (to be a percentage) and multiplied by a fixed value already in the worksheet `Sheets("Calcs").Range("DataStart").Offset(0, 6).Value`.

I've tried `Dim CRBinQnt as long`, short etc and `CDbl(CRBinQnt)` to no avail. Not sure why I keep getting mismatch error. Any help would be most appreciated. New to this, so if any further clarifications are required please let me know.

Comment: In case of the error what is the exact input in `CRBinQnt`? And what is the value in `Sheets("Calcs").Range("DataStart").Offset(0, 6).Value`?

Comment: CRBinQnt is a number, and Sheets("Calcs").Range("DataStart").Offset(0, 6).Value is too. I think I solved it. Basically, in my UserForm_Initialize all my other textbox base values (textboxname.Value) were 0. I added this one to have a default value of 0 too (newer testbox I added later). So I guess all my variables must be pre-defined in UserForm_Initialize to avoid mismatch errors. I'm not sure how correct this is, but it's working... Am I doing this correctly?

Comment: Please give the concrete values you used for testing that produced the error. It does not help if you tell these are numbers. That is why I asked for the **exact** input. The issue has nothing to do with `UserForm_Initialize`. In fact the issue is that the value of a TextBox is never a number as the name **Text**Box already says it returns text. So it depends on the exact input if/how we convert this text into a valid number.

Comment: So on the previous UserForm tab the inputs are saved to an Excel sheet. From these inputs, I run a calculation in the Excel sheet (output = Sheets("Calcs").Range("DataStart").Offset(0, 6).Value) This must be numeric as its the result of the calc. The CRBinQnt mentioned above is on the subsequent tab and I'm outputting it to the same Excel sheet, but I want what's inputted in the text box to undergo the mentioned calculation before being inputted to the Excel sheet. I have double clicked on the TextBox and AfterUpdate defined it as a Single. Yet, its still text? Hope this somewhat clarifies

Comment: This does not clarify because you did not answer my question. What is so difficult in answering my question about the **exact value** that you inputted in the textbox? Whatever you did does not work. You cannot define a textbox as `Single`. The `.Value` of the textbox is **always** `String` because (what I already explained) it is a **TEXT**Box. But to be able to answer your question I need to know how the numbers look like that you write into that textbox? Are they integers or decimals? What is used as decimal separator? Give an example for those numbers that produced the error.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. The Sheets("Calcs").Range("DataStart").Offset(0, 6).Value is a decimal. The CRBinQnt is an integer. No text. It is the percent value, which I want to then divide by 100 (to make a percent in my Excel) and times by the value (decimal) stated.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is using the following code for validating your TextBox `CRBinQnt`. The event `CRBinQnt_Exit` runs when the TextBox looses focus, so we validate its content.

```
Private Sub CRBinQnt_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    If Me.CRBinQnt.Value = vbNullString Then Exit Sub  ' this allows the TextBox to be left empty (if you don't want that remove it). If you don't allow it the user will be trapped in the TextBox until he enters a valid number. He even cannot abort.
    
    If Not IsNumeric(Me.CRBinQnt.Value) Then
        ' if the value is not numeric error and do not allow to leave the TextBox
        MsgBox "CRBinQnt needs to be an integer number!", vbExclamation
        Cancel = True
    ElseIf CStr(CLng(CRBinQnt.Value)) <> CRBinQnt.Value Then
        ' if the value is numeric check if it is an integer number, if not do not allow to leave the TextBox
        MsgBox "CRBinQnt needs to be an integer number!", vbExclamation
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Then you should be able to use this without getting an error.

```
If Not CRBinQnt.Value = vbNullString Then
    Sheets("Calcs").Range("DataStart").Offset(0, 11).Value = CLng(CRBinQnt.Value) / 100 * Sheets("Calcs").Range("DataStart").Offset(0, 6).Value
Else
    ' user did not input anything so abort …
End If
```